# Laravel Spark - user registration fails

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-spark

I have a clean install of Laravel 5.4 and Spark 4.0. Running only within Homestead for now.
When I try to register as a user, the screen flashes very briefly to a page full of errors, then returns to the registration form. Nothing is written to the DB.

I was able to run migrations. So, the application can connect to the DB.
I tried adding DD()s within the RegisterController, and get no output. So, I don't think I am hitting the controller.

Any ideas why Javascript validation is failing? (assuming that is the problem)

Comment: can you add more information?
usually is related to the configuration of spark